# Install latest version of packages with npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, npm, npm-install

It seems if I use `npm install --save <package_name>`, it installs the latest stable version.

I want to install the absolutely latest release. So if I, for instance, want to install Bootstrap v4, I need to do `npm install bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.6` instead of just `npm install bootstrap`.

But if I didn't know that the latest version is named `4.0.0-alpha.6`, I wouldn't be able to install it. Is there a flag or something else I can use to make sure I get the latest version?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the **@next** keyword to get the latest alpha/beta releases of a package.

In your case, it will be,

```
npm install bootstrap@next --save
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Great! Thanks! Is it possible to use with `npm-check-updates` which loops through all dependencies listed in `package.json` and updates them?

Comment: @Jamgreen Unfortunately, NCU will only update your packages with their **stable** releases, However what you can do is, you can update your `package.json` with `*` (instead of the version numbers) against all your packages to have it installed alpha/beta/unstable releases also

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
npm install bootstrap@next
```

This way you can install alpha/beta releases.